# Трейсинг API с использованием OpenTelemetry и Jaeger

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Пытаюсь добавить трейсы в API. Трейсы пишутся, но url не записывается (url.full всегда одинаковый, зпканчивается на "/_bulk") и всегда только один спан (похоже, спаны обращений к БД не создаются). Пакеты добавил во все проекты решения. Может быть, я что-то не так делаю?

```
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
.WithTracing(tracing => tracing
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
    .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
    .AddSqlClientInstrumentation()
    .AddOtlpExporter());
```